# Surprised by "inconsistent" behaviour of Matlab's rank function on small, integer-valued matrices

Tags: matlab, rank

Today I was quite surprised by this:

```
>> M = [0, 0, 0;6, 1, 3;1, 7, 0];
>> rank(M)

ans = 

    3

>> rank(M')

ans = 

    2
```

I'm aware of the fact that the rank function is not necessarily numerically stable since it thresholds the singular values. I was however expecting problems to happen for matrices that are either large in size or large in elements and not a 3 by 3 matrix of small integers.

I checked what happens and in fact svd(M) gives singular values 7.82, 5.93, 2.91e-15, while the default tolerance is only max(size(A))*eps(max(s)) = 2.665e-15. On the other hand, svd(M') gives 0 as third singular values (probably due to a whole column being zero).

Of course I can manually increase the tolerance in calling rank, but how would I know how far to increase it?

Is there another numerically stable method to compute the rank (say that we know that the matrix is integer)?

**edit**: I just found that this behavior is version-dependent. The above test was carried out with Matlab 2014a. On Matlab 2016b, svd(M) returns the third singular value as 4.15e-16 and rank works properly. So maybe there was indeed an issue with svd that was fixed between version. Still, I'm not sure anymore how far I can trust rank, so I believe my question remains valid.

Comment: Same effect as you have in 2014b, for the record.

Comment: On R2016b, `cond(M)` gives `5.046e15` and `cond(M.')` gives `inf`. Both `rank(M)` and `rank(M.')` give `2`

Comment: On my computer 
    cond(M) 
gives 
    1.884e16 
in R2016b and 
    2.69e15 
in R2014a. So in addition to the version, it might be platform-dependent. Great.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab 2015a/2015b seem to work (see below)

```
>> M = [0, 0, 0;6, 1, 3;1, 7, 0];
>> rank(M)

ans =

     2

>> rank(M')

ans =

     2

>>
```

Comment: Thanks, so according to the data, this was fixed between 2014b and 2015a.